# IOT instruction when converting string to word array

Tags: arrays, c, string, malloc

I'm coming back to you about my function `char **my_str_to_word_array(char *str)`. The purpose is to separate the string at each non-printable ASCII character and include the above in a new row of the double dimensional array.

Non-printable ASCII characters should be used as separators and should not be included in the line.

Example:

```c
char *test = "My name is John Doe.\nI have 0 GPA.\nI will survive." ;
char **array = my_str_to_word_array(test) ;

array[0] = "My name is John Doe." (zero terminated string)
array[1] = "I have 0 GPA." (zero terminated string)
array[2] = "I will survive." (zero terminated string)
array[3] = NULL
```

I have 2 problems:

1. If in my test `main()` I have a `printf()` below the call to my_str_to_word_array, the format passed to `printf()` will be included in the array. So I conclude that there is a memory read error.
2. When I try to `free()` the array I get an error :

```c
double free or corruption (out)
[1]    33429 IOT instruction (core dumped)  ./libmy
```

```c
size_t get_words_number(char const *str)
{
    size_t count = 0;
    const char *i = str;
    while (*i != 0) {
        if (isprint(*i)) {
            count++;
        }
        while (*i != 0 && isprint(*i)) {
            i++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return count;
}

char **free_corrupted_array(char **array, size_t i)
{
    size_t j = 0;
    while (j < i) {
        free(array[j]);
        j++;
    }
    free(array);
    return NULL;
}

char **fill_array(char **array, const char *str, size_t word_count)
{
    size_t word_size = 0, j = 0;
    const char *i = str;
    while (j < word_count) {
        while (*i != 0 && isprint(*i)) {
            word_size++;
            i++;
        }
        array[j] = strndup(i - word_size, word_size);
        if (!array[j]) {
            return free_corrupted_array(array, j);
        }
        word_size = 0;
        j++;
        while (!isprint(*i)) {
            i++;
        }
    }
    array[j] = NULL;
    return array;
}

char **my_str_to_word_array(char const *str)
{
    char **word_array = NULL;
    size_t word_count = 0;
    if (!str) {
        return NULL;
    }
    word_count = get_words_number(str);
    word_array = malloc(word_count * sizeof(char *));
    if (!word_array) {
        return NULL;
    }
    word_array = fill_array(word_array, str, word_count);
    return word_array;
}
```

```c
void my_free_word_array(char **word_array)
{
    if (!word_array) {
        return;
    }
    while (*word_array != NULL) {
        free(*word_array);
        word_array++;
    }
    free(word_array);
}
```

```c
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *test = "My name is John Doe.\nI have 0 GPA.\nI will survive.";
    char **word_array = my_str_to_word_array(test);
    while (*word_array != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", *word_array);
        word_array++;
    }
    printf("Test print original size %lu\n", strlen(test));
    my_free_word_array(word_array);
    return 0;
}
```

And the output :

```c
My name is John Doe.
I have 0 GPA.
I will survive.
Test print original size %lu
Test print original size 50
double free or corruption (out)
[1]    33429 IOT instruction (core dumped)  ./libmy
```

Do you see the problem?

Comment: ```word_array = malloc(size)``` ----> And then: 
 ```word_array = fill_array(word_array, str, word_count); ``` ---> You change what ```word_array``` was originally pointing to and lose all access to the dynamically allocated memory.  You then pass a pointer to ```free``` that wasn't dynamically allocated, hence the warning.

Comment: Among the multitude of problems in this code, look at `my_free_word_array`.  You're passing an address that itself was never the result of a dynamic allocation. The standard lib doesn't magically 'know' the address you passed was (maybe) somewhere 'within' a dynamic region, find its base, and free that. It's *your* job to do that housekeeping.

Comment: ```ptr1 = ptr2``` doesn't copy the contents of ```ptr2``` to ```ptr1```. It only copies the pointer value, such that both pointers now point to the same address.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but how do I fix it?

Comment: I edited the example to properly show that you want a NULL terminated array of C strings.

Comment: Virgil G., Detail: "zero terminated string"  is redundant in C.  All _strings_ contain a _null character_ at the end, else, it is not a string.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica — yabbut … novice C programmers need reminding that strings are null-terminated., and they need to ensure there's enough space for the null byte at the end of the string.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You can say that again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors:

1. `get_words_number` goes out of bounds (off by one) and may read arbitrary memory after your string (check with the example I included in `main`).
2. You need an additional slot in your array to put there a terminating `NULL`.
3. Stop thrashing your input pointer if you later need it (both in `my_free_word_array` and in the printing loop in `main`).
4. **EDITED**: as Fe2O3 commented, I missed another bug in the `fill_array` function. You should also ensure that `*i!=0` in the last loop.

Suggestions:

1. Next time make a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by including all required headers;
2. `strndup` is not standard (unless you have `__STDC_ALLOC_LIB__` and define `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT2__` to 1).
3. You don't need the `free_corrupted_array` function at all.
4. **EDITED**: it's useless to check that `*i!=0` if you are also checking that `isprint(*i)`. `0` is not printable, so no need for the first check.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#ifdef __STDC_ALLOC_LIB__
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT2__ 1
#else
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char *strndup(const char *str, size_t size)
{
    return strncpy(calloc(size + 1, 1), str, size);
}
#endif

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

size_t get_words_number(char const *str)
{
    size_t count = 0;
    const char *i = str;
    while (*i != 0) {
        if (isprint(*i)) {
            count++;
        }
        while (*i != 0 && isprint(*i)) {
            i++;
        }
        if (*i != 0) { // <--- This was missing
            i++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

void my_free_word_array(char **word_array) // <--- Moved up
{
    if (!word_array) {
        return;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; word_array[i] != NULL; ++i) { // <--- Stop thrashing word_array
        free(word_array[i]);
    }
    free(word_array);
}

char **fill_array(char **array, const char *str, size_t word_count)
{
    size_t word_size = 0, j = 0;
    const char *i = str;
    while (j < word_count) {
        while (*i != 0 && isprint(*i)) {
            word_size++;
            i++;
        }
        array[j] = strndup(i - word_size, word_size); 
        if (!array[j]) {
            my_free_word_array(array); // <--- No need for another free here
            return NULL;
        }
        word_size = 0;
        j++;
        while (*i != 0 && !isprint(*i)) {
            i++;
        }
    }
    array[j] = NULL;
    return array;
}

char **my_str_to_word_array(char const *str)
{
    char **word_array = NULL;
    size_t word_count = 0;
    if (!str) {
        return NULL;
    }
    word_count = get_words_number(str);
    word_array = malloc((word_count + 1) * sizeof(char *)); // <--- You need a +1 here
    if (!word_array) {
        return NULL;
    }
    word_array = fill_array(word_array, str, word_count);
    return word_array;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char test[] = "My name is John Doe.\nI have 0 GPA.\nI will survive.\nThis will be removed from the string";
    *strrchr(test,'\n') = 0;
    char **word_array = my_str_to_word_array(test);
    if (word_array) {
        for (size_t i = 0; word_array[i] != NULL; ++i) { // <--- Stop thrashing word_array
            printf("%s\n", word_array[i]);
        }
        printf("Test print original size %zu\n", strlen(test));
        my_free_word_array(word_array);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OP's code missed a check for a *null character*. [@Costantino Grana](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74964662/2410359)

**Candidate `get_words_number()` correction and simplification:**

Count transitions from "non-word" to "word".

Use `unsigned char*` for defined use for all characters in `is...()` functions.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

size_t get_words_number(char const *str) {
  const unsigned char *ustr = (const unsigned char *) str;
  size_t count = 0;
  bool previous_not_a_word = true;
  
  while (*ustr) {
    count += previous_not_a_word && isprint(*ustr);
    previous_not_a_word = !isprint(*ustr);
    ustr++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: Nice one. You're missing a `ustr++`, otherwise it would be an infinite loop. I detected this by using [Compiler Explorer](godbolt.org) to check if `isprint` would have been called more than once. It's not.

Comment: @CostantinoGrana I used to code things to directly avoid things like a `isprint(*ustr)` re-call.  Yet since compilers are getting smarter, I leave it them to handle such basic optimizations and focus my time on bigger things.  Thanks for reporting the error and testing the optimization.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem with the OP code is that it has been fractured into so many helper functions that it is almost unreadable. A simple process has been muddied by this fragmentation.

Below is a "single pass" version that solves this problem. It does not involve helper functions with their parameters and maddening variable names.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    // OP string still as "string literal"
    char *test = "My name is John Doe.\nI have 0 GPA.\nI will survive.";

    // mutable copy of that string
    char *copy = malloc( strlen( test ) + 1 ); // Verify!
    strcpy( copy, test );

    // get one element that is NULL
    size_t cnt = 0;
    char **arr = calloc( ++cnt, sizeof *arr ); // Verify!!

    // chop copy on separators
    char *cp = copy;
    while( *cp ) {
        // skip leading/trailing separators
        while( *cp && !isprint( *cp ) ) cp++;
        if( !*cp ) break; // was 1 or more trailing seps

        // search for end of segment
        char *ep = cp;
        while( isprint( *ep ) ) ep++;

        // remember if this is the final segment
        bool atEnd = *ep == '\0';

        // terminate segment and store pointer
        *ep = '\0';
        arr = realloc( arr, ++cnt * sizeof *arr ); // Verify!!!
        arr[ cnt-2 ] = cp;
        arr[ cnt-1 ] = NULL;

        // move on (only if there is more to examine).
        cp = ep + !atEnd;
    }

    // output
    cnt = 0;
    do
        printf( "%d: %s\n", cnt, arr[ cnt ] ? arr[ cnt ] : "END OF ARRAY" );
    while( arr[ cnt++ ] );

    // cleanup
    free( arr );
    free( copy );

    return 0;
}
```

The crucial verifications of return values from the heap allocation functions have been deliberately omitted to improve the clarity of this example code. Those verifications are left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I understand your point of view, the reason why I subdivide into sub-functions is that my school forbids me to have more than 20 rows, each row must be a maximum of 80 columns and I am not allowed more than 2 loops / nested conditional structures.

I am not allowed to use libC (except malloc() in this case), so I have recoded all the functions that are called in this program.

Comment: Silly, arbitrary constraints... Clear concise code should be the constraint, imho... "80 columns"?! Tell your instructors the world has moved on from Hollerith cards. Funny... we're almost 1.4 through this century and "punched card" was dead before the end of the previous century...

Comment: I know... the pdf of what they call "Coding Style" is 25 pages long... and it's very complicated to follow...