# Can anyone explain what IOT instruction (core dumped) refers to?

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

I’m getting the following problem when executing a C program:

```bash
~$ ./a.out
zsh IOT instruction (core dumped) ./a.out
```

I’ve never seen this before, and I don’t know how to solve it. What is it?

Please not that I’m not looking for a solve to this problem, but to understand what the problem is, so I can fix it. Google has yielded nothing that helps.

Comment: my first google hit https://superuser.com/questions/1284627/what-does-iot-mean-in-regards-to-sigiot for `IOT instruction` and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75103356/iot-instruction-when-freeing-a-malloced-array and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74963659/iot-instruction-when-converting-string-to-word-array

Comment: @KamilCuk: So SIGIOT is just an alias for SIGABRT.  Raising the interesting question of why you would get the message "IOT instruction" rather than the usual "Aborted" message that would correspond naturally to SIGABRT.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

tl;dr: It means that `abort()` was called.  And now, you have to figure out *why* it was called.  (The core dump might help.)

But, why the strange message?  I decided to look into it.

Once upon a time, there was a computer called the [PDP-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11).  It had an instruction named `IOT`, "I/O Trap" which would cause a certain type of trap to the operating system.  It seems that Unix on the PDP/11  would handle this trap by delivering a specific signal to the process, whose numeric value was assigned to the macro `SIGIOT` in `<signal.h>`.

The macro is still supported by modern Linux, probably so that old programs that hardcode a list of signal macros would still compile.  However, [it's assigned to the same number (6) as the more common `SIGABRT`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/asm-generic/signal.h#L16-L17), which is the signal raised when `abort()` is called.  So in effect, `SIGIOT` is merely a legacy alias for `SIGABRT`.

But the message?  We're getting to that.  Keep in mind that the macro names `SIGIOT` and `SIGABRT` only exist at compile time; at runtime, all a process would see is the integer value 6.  To translate it to something human-readable, the usual way is to call the standard library `strsignal` function.  On Linux with glibc, `strsignal(6)` returns the string `Aborted` which is quite reasonable.  This is what most shells would use to report the signal that killed your process.

But zsh, for some reason, wants to be different.  They don't use the standard `strsignal` function, but rather they roll their own.  They have a pair of scripts ([`signame1.awk`](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/master/tree/Src/signames1.awk) [`signame2.awk`](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/master/tree/Src/signames1.awk)) that parse the system's `signal.h` file to see what signals exist, then generate a lookup table to map the numeric values to predefined strings.  The awk code looks like:

```
    if (signam == "ABRT")   { msg[signum] = "abort" }
    if (signam == "ALRM")   { msg[signum] = "alarm" }
    # ...
    if (signam == "IO")     { msg[signum] = "i/o ready" }
    if (signam == "IOT")    { msg[signum] = "IOT instruction" }
    if (signam == "KILL")   { msg[signum] = "killed" }
    # ...
```

And now you see the issue.  Since `SIGABRT` is defined as 6, when the script processes the line `#define SIGABRT 6` from `<signal.h>`, it will set `msg[6] = "abort"`.  Which would be fine.  But `SIGIOT` is *also* defined as 6, so when it gets to processing that line, it will set `msg[6] = "IOT instruction"`, replacing the previous string.

As a result, with zsh, the commonplace `SIGABRT` signal gets reported with the outlandish `IOT instruction` message.  This is arguably a small bug in zsh.  It's been [reported](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1014383) as a Debian bug, but does not seem to have been reported upstream.

A side effect, which is a little more serious, is that `kill -ABRT` doesn't work under zsh; to send the abort signal you would have to `kill -IOT` instead, which probably nobody knows to do.

I've just sent a message to the zsh-workers mailing list about it.

Comment: Now people can tell which shell I'm using from looking at my browser search history. That's new :D